# Elasticsearch page visible from localhost but not from remote server

Tags: elasticsearch, centos

`Elasticsearch 7.0.0` is configured like that on `CentOS 7.6`
:

`sudo cat /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`:

```
cluster.name: elk-log-elasticsearch
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
http.port: 9200
```

From inside server:
 `curl --verbose http://127.0.0.1:9200`

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< content-length: 525
<
{
  "name" : "Cardif.software.altkom.pl",
  "cluster_name" : "elk-log-elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "rTMG9hXBTk-CuA73G9KHSA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.0.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "rpm",
    "build_hash" : "b7e28a7",
    "build_date" : "2019-04-05T22:55:32.697037Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.0.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.7.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

From outside of this server (name it 'A'), on server 'B' i can ping server 'A':
I know that it's IP is like: 172.16.xx.x

I can enter Kibana on: http://172.16.xx.x:5601 in browser, but i can not enter
Elasticsearch page on http://172.16.xx.x:9200

How can i change config to make it work?

Ports are enabled in firewalld:

```
firewall-cmd --list-all

  ports: 5432/tcp 80/tcp 5601/tcp 5602/tcp 9200/tcp 9201/tcp 15672/tcp 8080/tcp 8081/tcp 8082/tcp 5488/tcp
```

I tried:
1)

```
  network.host : 0.0.0.0
```

2)

```
network.bind_host: 172.x.x.x
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.seed_hosts: 127.0.0.1
```